# Repeated measurements graph per individual

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a question about how to draw subject specific graphs with longitudinal data in R.

My data has the following format:

```
    Id    x0    x1    x2
    1     2     5     6
    2     2     3     2
    3     6     4     3
```

Id is the patient ID, x is a variable that is measured on timepoint 0, 1 and 2.
I have a vector z, which represents the time:

```
    z <- c(0, 3, 6)
```

So x0 is measured on timepoint 0, x1 is measured on timepoint 3 and x2 is measured on timepoint 6.

I want to create three different graps, so one for each individual. I want the time, so the z vector on the x-axis. The y-axis should contain the values of x.
How can I do this in R?

I hope my question is clear, as it is hard to explain it clearly.

Thank you in advance.

Lisa

Comment: Can you make a sketch of what the output should look like? Do you want bar plots? or lines or points? And generally you should show what code you've tried so far and describe where you are getting stuck. Questions that are nothing more than "please do this for me" are frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Source data:

```
patient_data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
    Id    x0    x1    x2
    1     2     5     6
    2     2     3     2
    3     6     4     3")
```

Here I tie the time values you specified to the column names in the first table:

```
time_names = names(patient_data) 
z <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  time_val = c(0, 3, 6),
  time_lab = time_names[2:length(time_names)]
)
```

Now join the two and graph:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
patient_data %>%
  tidyr::gather(time_lab, value, -Id) %>%
  left_join(z) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time_val, value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Id)
```

[image]